# re-exporting ES6 modules with webpack and ts-loader

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, webpack

I have a typescript project which uses ES6 style syntax for importing and exporting content in a module, the problem is I have a webpack entry point which does something like:

```
export {Something} from "./some-file";
```

However when I go to include the outputted webpack module like so:

```
import {Something} from "./some-webpack-bundle"
```

So is this to be expected and do I need to tell webpack to manually expose `Something` or is there some quick way to resolve these sort of re-export scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being an idiot, all other aspects were exporting as libraries however this one was not, so the above code should work fine assuming you export your webpack bundle as a library (we use UMD).